# Android - send view to back

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin within an Ionic app to view my device's camera and then stream over RTMP - https://github.com/disono/cordova-rtmp-rtsp-stream

This works great, but I need the Ionic webview to appear over the top of the camera so that I can show images & text on top of the camera view. Can someone tell me how to edit the plugin to place the camera view behind Ionic's webview please?

Unfortunately I do not know the Java language, but I believe the file that requires editing may be [RTMPActivity.java](https://github.com/disono/cordova-rtmp-rtsp-stream/blob/master/src/android/com/webmons/disono/rtmpandrtspstreamer/RTMPActivity.java)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You'll need an absolute Java mastermind to achieve such a thing, I honestly don't think it would be possible to do such a thing with Cordova.

Comment: I've seen several plugins that do it, including this one https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview